# How to use downloaded fonts with XeTeX on Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am wanting to use the [Fontin](http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html) font in my XeTeX document.

What steps should I do for dowloading the font (should I choose TTF or OpenType) and where should it be stored (on Ubuntu)? How can XeTeX find this font?

I am using TexLive 2011 installed in a custom location (/somepath/texlive/2011)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Install the fonts in `/usr/local/share/fonts` if you want them system-wide or in `~/.fonts` if you want them only for the current user:

```
$ sudo cp Fontin*.otf /usr/local/share/fonts
```

You can then check for the font in `fc-list`:

```
$ fc-list : family file | grep -i fontin
/usr/local/share/fonts/Fontin-SmallCaps.otf: Fontin SmallCaps,Fontin
/usr/local/share/fonts/Fontin-Italic.otf: Fontin
/usr/local/share/fonts/Fontin-Bold.otf: Fontin
/usr/local/share/fonts/Fontin-Regular.otf: Fontin
```

which gives you the name to use in XeTeX (using `fontspec`). For example:

```
\setmainfont{Fontin}
```

Comment: Shouldn't one run `fc-cache` for using the font immediately?

Comment: @egreg: I thought so too for some time, and then I realized that it's automatically run on Ubuntu whenever you copy fonts to `/usr/local/share/fonts`. You can actually see it because the terminal is refreshed a second or so after you do the copy. That said, it doesn't hurt to run `fc-cache` anyway.

Comment: Do I understand right that I have to download the OpenType font?

Comment: Nice to know; it may be necessary on other systems, though.

Comment: I assume I have to install fonts in ~/.fonts for user only fonts. Do I have to run fc-cache then?

Comment: @PeterSmit: generally speaking, the OpenType font will have more features. I haven't tried with `~/.fonts` but I think it should work.