# How to attach True Type Fonts in TeX Live LaTeX

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

The problem is: where one can read *precise instruction* on how to 
effectively install Windows "Truefonts" (`.ttf` files) in TeX Live LaTeX
environment installed in Windows XP? But please, do not drive me to 
(from the other hand valuable) article written by S. Kroonenberg called [Font installation the shallow way](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb27-1/tb86kroonenberg-fonts.pdf). I know it.

Comment: If you tell us, which font you'd like to use in your document, and what kind of document it is, we might come up with better advise.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of messing with the font installations, you may want to simply use the XeTeX engine, which is available through TexLive and is able to use the TrueType fonts installed on the system. Since I'm a Linux user myself, I'm not too sure whether it is installed by default or not. Once it is installed, you can compile your documents with e.g.

```
xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode myfile.tex
```

instead of the usual

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode myfile.tex
```

You may want to configure your editor to use xelatex by default. The font declarations with xelatex are very straightforward. For [Example](http://existentialtype.net/2008/07/12/fonts-in-latex-part-one-xelatex/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}
Testing XeLaTeX!

\end{document}
```

You will need to know the names of the fonts available on your system. This [list of names](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/winxp.htm) may help you with that.

Note that TexLive also provides the Times font, which is very similar to Times New Roman, and which you can load simply with `\usepackage{mathptmx}`. This works with regular pdflatex, so you don't have to install anything. Further, the Helvetica font is very similar to Arial and is available with the `helvet` package. The [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) provides a good overview of fonts and font packages, many of which are available with TexLive.

Answer (score 4):

The 'standard' way to install fonts in LaTeX is discribed in the [fontinstallationguide](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontinstallationguide?lang=en) by using Postscript Type1 fonts. You can use `fontforge` or tools like `ttf2pt1` to create them. There are also scripts like [installfont(-tl)](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/installfont?lang=en) doing the job for you.

See also: [How to use downloaded fonts with pdfLaTeX on Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27755/how-to-use-downloaded-fonts-with-pdflatex-on-ubuntu/27785#27785)

Comment: It's 2012. XeTeX and LuaTeX exist. Use them and forget about PostScript Type 1 fonts and old engines like pdfTeX.