# OTF and VFB fonts in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

I have a `ttf` font that I like and I would like to use it in my documents, the creators of this fonts are also sharing a folder called `src` with `otf` and `vfb` files in it with this patterns:

- *Font*-Regular.otf
- *Font*-Regular.vfb
- *Font*-Regular-OTF.vfb
- *Font*-Regular-TTF.vfb

Since I haven't found a really good guide about how to make a LaTeX font out of a `ttf` one, I'm wondering if and how I can use those files in my LaTeX documents, thanks.

Comment: VFB files are FontLab (a font editor) internal file formats, so they are of no use other than opening them with it. For OTF or TTF fonts you can use XeTeX or LuaTeX if you want to avoid the pain of setting them up in PDFTeX.

Comment: @KhaledHosny the problem is that for the really short period of time I have used latex for my documents, I have learned that using extensions it's not really worth the trouble, especially because in the latex world there are really old packages, and packages that are newer, extensions often times do not work out of the box and some tools are platform-specific. So I would like to know what is the internal representation of a font in latex so at least, after "facing the pain" of a conversion, I can at least work with a real latex font without the need for packages or extra tools.

Comment: Check the “Related” links on the right side of the page, some of them should answer your question (like the one mentioning `otfinst.py`).

Comment: @KhaledHosny it's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, I'm trying to get "native" font metrics for latex out of this, the problem is that I have no idea what is the internal representation of a font accepted by latex and how its font-cache ( if any ) works. I would like to read something about this and know about to create this kind of fonts.

Comment: Are these of interest? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52819/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-pdftex-using-otftotfm http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1472/586

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I just want details on what a font is under latex. Filetypes, specifications, something like that. For example, what is the role of the several directories and type found under `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/` ? http://pastebin.com/feHrFEGY

Comment: ok, now I get that the `tfm` ones are files containing the metrics for a given font that is specifically designed for latex, so in latex there is a dedicated file for the font metric, after this what more do I need to complete the idea of font under latex ?

Comment: http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm

Comment: @KhaledHosny i found another guide that is more verbose and it explain this a slightly better way, I still have to try the steps though . I will update this shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, TeX (and LaTeX) knows only boxes. The information for a character (which is a box) is contained in the `.tfm` files.

The simplest way to go, at least if you don't use  the font for mathematical formulae, is to use the `fontspec` package and compile with `xelatex`. Just write in the preamble:
`\setmainfont{name-of-the-font}`, where `name-of-the-font` is its name, as known to your operating system – if you want to use Sabon Next LT Pro, just say:

```
\setmainfont{Sabon Next LT Pro}
```

You must not use the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages, but must ensure that your source code is in `utf8` encoding.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). See our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) for more about how the site works.