# Truetype fonts for dummies?

Tags: fonts, truetype

So I have written a few papers in LaTeX. It does what I want it to, most of the time; my knowledge allows me to ask the right questions, at least. There is one noticeable exception, though: fonts.

I am not using Computer Modern (ever), and have happily used CTAN-provided font packages since day 1. Recently I even managed to get Minion Pro up and running. Every now and then, however, there's a special font I'd like to use, usually of the TrueType variety. More often than not, these are not free (or they are not of sufficient interest to the public at large), so there is no simple package for me to use. My question is: how and where do I learn how to create one? How do I go from my .ttf font to `\usepackage{fontnamehere}`?

I am ready, willing and able to read, learn and follow instructions, but where do I even start?

PS: Please do not suggest either LuaTeX or XeTeX, which unfortunately are not an option in my case.

Comment: Does this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52819/4918

Comment: I'll take a look. This one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex did not, unfortunately (and was the only one I found)

Comment: and this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6306477

Comment: What about the answer of [Christopher Oezbek](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1472/4918) in the question you found? Could you explain why LuaTeX/XeTeX aren’t alternatives?

Comment: @Tobi: as he he writes "Create a package/sty to pull the various fonts into a font family (this is where I am stuck)". Well, so am I. I'll try to duplicate his steps until there, though. Unfortunately it all needs to be pdf(La)TeX, it's a publisher's requirement.

Comment: The linked page (http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm) give some instructions on how to use such a font in LaTeX. If you want a package have a look at other font packages to get an idea how it works …

Comment: Furthermore the manual linked in the answer below explains how to make a package.

Comment: why is xetex not an option? It makes using any font installed at your system level trivially easy, and using truetype with classic TeX is hard at best and gets much harder still if you need to access characters out of the rangel of 8bit tex as you need to make multiple fonts covering 256c characters at a time and then have tex support macros to use the right one in each case

Comment: If pdflatex is OK (as opposed to latex), you can use truetype fonts directly (without converting them) which will give better results. You can still use the font installation guide. Almost everything works but you should probably add the map file in your .sty file rather than adding it using updmap/updmap-sys.

Comment: Also, you *must* reencode the font (even if it is a symbol font).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to learn how to create a support package for a font to use with `(pdf)latex`, there's the almighty [fontinstallationguide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontinstallationguide). Tutorial I describes how to create support files for PostScript Type1 fonts. I've written a [bash script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/installfont) that automates exactly these steps.

Then it shouldn't be much more than something like:

```
installfont -f 5na -n ’Softmaker Nashville’ -c Nashville -P MF@Sna -v v1.0 -l /cygdrive/d/LocalTeXMF -s MyFonts/Nashville -p nashville -m nashville -O -d 2010/09/14
```

If automatic renaming of the fonts works! ;-)