# OTF installation - error - files must be included entirely

Tags: fonts, pdf, miktex, installing

Argh! Maybe the fonts I got are useless?
I got a set of OTF fonts and am trying to install them for use with MikTeX pdflatex.
(Yes I know about XeTeX and LuaTeX and that it could be easier with them. Unfortunately,
for various reasons, we're using pdflatex.)

When I use the work flow described here, 
[How do I use TrueType Fonts with PDFTeX using otftotfm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52819/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-pdftex-using-otftotfm)
(modified for MikTeX 2.9), I get the following
error message when compiling with pdflatex:

```
'OTF Files must be included entirely'
```

Is there something I need to do to insure the entire OTF file is included?
(I thought pdflatex only embeds those glyphs discovered in the document?)

p.s.
I found this old old link, http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2003-January/003412.html
and not much else when googling/and searching here. I doubt I'm the only person experiencing this. Can it be I'm using sub-optimal keywords?

Comment: What is the content of the map-file created by the workflow?

Comment: '% Automatically maintained by otftotfm or other programs. Do not edit.'  
  
'berkeleystd-book--lcdfj BerkeleyStd-BookLCDFJ "" <BerkeleyStd-BookLCDFJ.pfb'  
'berkeleystd-book--base BerkeleyStd-Book "AutoEnc_5yjl5y33w6e7fvg5fphscaz2jd ReEncodeFont" <[a_5yjl5y.enc <berkeleystd-book.otf'

Comment: `<<BerkeleyStd-BookLCDFJ.pfb` should do full inclusion.

Comment: The second entry with .otf at the end should use `<<` instead of `<`. pdflatex can't subset otf-fonts. With the pfb `<` should be ok.

Comment: Thanks - I still think the original font file has Problems. the pdflatex run completes and creates the pdf, but without a font. Now I get a slew of the following line (with various characters)     'Missing character: There is no e in font T1-berkeleystd-book--lcdfj!
Missing character: There is no t in font T1-berkeleystd-book--lcdfj!
Missing character: There is no e in font T1-berkeleystd-book--lcdfj!
Missing character: There is no r in font T1-berkeleystd-book--lcdfj!

Comment: Just as a sanity check: can you use the font in other applications?

Comment: A lot things can go wrong when installing fonts for pdflatex. But it is not possible to guess what happened in your case.

Comment: @cfr - when clicking on the files themselves, Windows Pops up a font Viewer, which Displays the Fonts.

Comment: If the Fonts are Unicode, and my *tex is latin1, am I asking for Problems? I believe pdflatex can handle the combination of Unicode and non-Unicode Fonts - am I mistaken?

Comment: The input encoding of the tex-file is irrelevant. And pdflatex can handle various font encodings. As there is not "e" and "t" in your tfm's it is improbable that your tex document is at faults. It sounds as if something did go seriously wrong during the creation of all the helper files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As egreg and Ulrike commented, using two greater-than signs

```
'<<'
```

got rid of the offending error message that I asked about.

(I still have Problems with using the fonts, but thats due to other Problems - probably with the font files themselves.)

Comment: egreg and Ulrike provided the answer in the comments above- if any up-votes are assigned, click up there. I only noted that their Suggestion(s) worked.