# Using OTF fonts with pdflatex

Tags: fonts, otftotfm

I'm trying to use a `.otf` font I downloaded with `pdflatex`. I know that I could just use `XeLaTeX` to make it work, but I want to stick with `pdflatex`.

Having downloaded the latest version of LCDF-Typetools, I tried running

```
otftotfm -a -e texnansx FedraSerifBPro-Book.otf
```

on one of the four files of the font family, but got the error

```
otftotfm: encoding 'texnansx' not found
```

even though I have that file, as shown by running

```
kpsewhich texnansx.enc
```

Up until this point I placed the otf files in my home tex tree, i.e. in

```
~/Library/texmf/fonts/opentype/FedraSerifBPro
```

but even moving the folder to the texlive tree, i.e. in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/FedraSerifBPro
```

I still get the error saying that the encoding cannot be found.

I suspect that maybe I don't have the `kpathsea` path finder. Is there a way to see if this is the problem, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/ummels/fedraserif ?

Comment: I used that font just as an example, I'm more interested in the general procedure than in getting this specific font to work.

Comment: otftotfm doesn't know about kpathsea, which should it? Beside this, better use the autoinst script.

Comment: I got the idea that otftotfm uses kpathsea from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52902/172923). In the `log` file, the first line says `otftotfm: encoding file ec.enc found with kpathsea at /opt/tex/texlive/qstex/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/ec.enc`

Comment: Also, if I'm not wrong `autoinst` uses `otftotfm`, so the problem would remain.

Comment: I have two otftotfm: one in the texlive 2019 bin folder and one that I downloaded at some time and installed manually. The one in texlive 2019 finds the encoding file without problem, the other not.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think I have both as well, since I installed `lcdftypetools` (which contains `otftotfm`) through homebrew before realising that `otftotfm` is already present in texlive. How do I know which one I'm using, and how can I switch between the two?

Comment: no idea, I'm on windows. There I use `where` to check the path, and set the path variable to switch.

Comment: I had indeed two versions of `otftotfm`, I uninstalled the one from homebrew and now it seems to work as it should. If you want you can make an answer out of these comments, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't expect an externally installed otftotfm to know about kpathsea, and a test confirmed this:

I have two `otftotfm`: one in the texlive 2019 bin folder and one that I downloaded at some time and installed manually.

The one in texlive 2019 finds the encoding file without problem, the other not.

Answer (score 11):

I always use `autoinst`. For example:

```
 autoinst FedraSansStd-Book.otf FedraSansStd-Bold.otf FedraSansStd-BoldItalic.otf FedraSansStd-BookItalic.otf
```

creates all font files for use with pdflatex and save it automatically in the correct directories for the local tree. E.g.: in `usr/local/texlive/texmflocal/latex/FedraSansStd` with the files

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 1933 Jun  9 21:07 FedraSansStd.sty
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3568 Jun  9 21:07 LY1FedraSansStd-LF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3631 Jun  9 21:07 LY1FedraSansStd-OsF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 2059 Jun  9 21:07 LY1FedraSansStd-Sup.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3631 Jun  9 21:07 LY1FedraSansStd-TLF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3694 Jun  9 21:07 LY1FedraSansStd-TOsF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3568 Jun  9 21:07 OT1FedraSansStd-LF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3631 Jun  9 21:07 OT1FedraSansStd-OsF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 2059 Jun  9 21:07 OT1FedraSansStd-Sup.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3631 Jun  9 21:07 OT1FedraSansStd-TLF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3694 Jun  9 21:07 OT1FedraSansStd-TOsF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3527 Jun  9 21:07 T1FedraSansStd-LF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3590 Jun  9 21:07 T1FedraSansStd-OsF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 2037 Jun  9 21:07 T1FedraSansStd-Sup.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3590 Jun  9 21:07 T1FedraSansStd-TLF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 3653 Jun  9 21:07 T1FedraSansStd-TOsF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 2026 Jun  9 21:07 TS1FedraSansStd-LF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 2059 Jun  9 21:07 TS1FedraSansStd-OsF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 2059 Jun  9 21:07 TS1FedraSansStd-TLF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 2092 Jun  9 21:07 TS1FedraSansStd-TOsF.fd
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 2015 Jun  9 21:07 UFedraSansStd-Orn.fd
```

and also for the `tfm`, `pfb` a.s.o. always in a subdirectory `lcdeftools`

Comment: Mh something's not working for me here. After I launch the autoinst I get like twenty times is a row the warning `otftotfm: too many arguments`, and at the end of those warnings I get `[WARNING] 'otftotfm' returned non-zero; something's wrong!'`. The original question was about `otftotfm`; using `autoinst` isn't going to work if I have problems with `otftotfm`, since it uses it.

Comment: I too prefer autoinst, which is one of a best ....