# Using Font "Barlow" in PDFLatex?

Tags: fonts

I would like to use the Font "Barlow", however it is not listed in the font catalogue https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/

Im compiling my .tex files with PDFLatex. Right now, im using the font "Robot", which is included in the catalogue.

Is there any way to implement Barlow to PDFLatex? Thx!

Comment: if you have Barlow installed in your operating system you can use it with lualatex or xelatex, they are not restricted to "tex fonts"

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use pdflatex specifically? While [there are methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52819/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-pdftex-using-otftotfm) for using ttf fonts or converting them for use with pdflatex, using xelatex or lualatex is typically a much easier process.

Comment: I have no specific reason. I use a lot of usepackages on pdflatex and I have no experience with XeLaTeX and lualatex. I will study these two latex types. I even don't know how to download them and which editor I have to use.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you have pdflatex installed and don't have them installed as well already. You can use the same editor you're using now; you may have to tweak its configuration. If you say which one, we can give you hints. Your code probably has to change very little apart from the packages having to do with fonts (and you can drop inputenc if you have that loaded).

Comment: Yes plese! I am using texshop. My files inculedes dozents of usepackages. One for example is tikzpicture. As I have read, tikz should work on xetex too. So how i am gonna compile the same files with the font barlow? Right now i am compiling the files as "pdflatex". Thanks a lot! Yes i have inputenc right now. So i delet it?