# Palatino package and fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I want to use the *palatino* package in XeLaTeX but I often use accented letters so I also load the package *fontspec*. However, after loading the fontspec package I get the error:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'EU1/ppl/m/n' undefined using 'EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 10.

And even without the *fontspec* package the math symbols are in not in the desired palatino font.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You need to use Unicode math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't already have them, then install `Tex Gyre Pagella` and `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` from the [TeX Gyre project](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) and then you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
Some Unicode maths: $x ∈ ℕ$ in a Palatino-like font.
\end{document}
```

Run with `xelatex` to get:

[image]

Note that `unicode-math` package loads `fontspec` automatically.

Comment: Is there an easy way to install these fonts?

Comment: Sure - it depends on your platform - for OSX just open the downloaded OTF files in Font Book and click on the little button at the bottom of the preview that says "Install Font".  For Linux try [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27659/how-to-use-downloaded-fonts-with-xetex-on-ubuntu).  For Windows, I'm afraid I no longer know.

Comment: @David You don't need to install them if you have a current TeX installation and `fontconfig` is setup to recognise the relevant TeX font directories. (Typically Linux systems are set up like this. I don't know about OS X or other Unix-type systems, but they mostly use fontconfig so it should be easy to make any required change. No idea about Windows even if it uses fontconfig.)

Comment: And how to use the *ams* package with the *unicode-math*?

Comment: @David add `\usepackage{mathtools}` **before** `\usepackage{unicode-math}`.